# Workaround for Sonarqube rule: ' Remove usage of generic wildcard type' in dynamic return

Tags: java, sonarqube

Addressing a '*code smell*' on one of my endpoints where I set the body return type dynamically. The logic will return either an APPLICATION.PDF or MEDIATYPE.IMAGE_PNG. This works as-is, but was wondering if there is a more proper way

```
@GetMapping(value = "/form", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrieveForm(@RequestParam String formType,
                                          @RequestParam String form,
                                          @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean responseTypePng
    ) {
        byte[] formAsBytes =  manager.retrieveForm(formType, form);

        if(!responseTypePng) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(formAsBytes);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                .body(PDFConverterUtility.convertToPNG(formAsBytes));
    }
```

[image]